# Как переименовать группу файлов?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Группа файлов именуется как shot????.png (? - цифры). Нужно отбросить приставку shot, т.е. из shot0000.png получить 0000.png, а из shot9999.png получить 9999.png. Я сейчас смотрю, как прикрутить подходящий regex в bash, но, может, я все усложняю, и это делается гораздо проще? Если так, буду признателен за наводку.

Comment: Я взорвал себе мозг, но не смог придумать способа проще, чем написание скрипта на Питоне. Всё время напарываюсь на какой-то странное поведение…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in shot[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png; do mv $i ${i/shot/}; done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
prename 's/shot(\d+)/$1/g' *.png
```

Правда, оно нерекурсивное и, видимо, нужен установленный перл (думаю, в убунте перл предустановлен)

Comment: Ух, чё только не придумают!

Comment: На убунте перл установлен и команда работает на отлично. :)